# Where should I put code for automatic database updates?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have made a simple app that displays data supplied by an Firebase realtime database. As it is now the user have to manually trigger the updating of data.

I want to make the app automatically update if the user has not manually done it for a while. I was thinking of putting the code in `onCreate()` so that its updated everytime a user opens the app.

But if I understand the activity lifecycle correctly `onResume()` will be called if the user doesn't close it but rather just keeps it in the background for a long time. But if I put the code in `onResume()` it will be triggered to often.

How are automatic updates like this usually handled and where could I put the code to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's conventional to add database listeners in onStart when an activity is becomes visible, and remove them in onStop when the activity becomes invisible.